# No guarda la variable de session en un php alojado en donweb

Tags: php, php7, php5, session, sesiones

Tengo un problema que tenia un codigo funcionando en un servidor con php5. lo tuve que cambiar a donweb y alli hay php 7. el mismo codigo me trae problema con las sessiones... entonces encontre un codigo php para testear que es este... y realmente me indica que no guarda la variable.

```
<?php
session_start();

$sessPath   = ini_get('session.save_path');
$sessCookie = ini_get('session.cookie_path');
$sessName   = ini_get('session.name');
$sessVar    = 'foo';

echo '<br>sessPath: ' . $sessPath;
echo '<br>sessCookie: ' . $sessCookie;

echo '<hr>';
if( !isset( $_GET['p'] ) ){
    // instantiate new session var
    $_SESSION[$sessVar] = 'hello world';
}else{
    if( $_GET['p'] == 1 ){
        // printing session value and global cookie PHPSESSID
        echo $sessVar . ': ';
        if( isset( $_SESSION[$sessVar] ) ){
            echo $_SESSION[$sessVar];
        }else{
            echo '[not exists]';
        }
        echo '<br>' . $sessName . ': ';
        if( isset( $_COOKIE[$sessName] ) ){
        echo $_COOKIE[$sessName];
        }else{
            if( isset( $_REQUEST[$sessName] ) ){
            echo $_REQUEST[$sessName];
            }else{
                if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] ) ){
                echo $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'];
                }else{
                echo 'problem, check your PHP settings';
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
       // destroy session by unset() function
        unset( $_SESSION[$sessVar] );
        // check if was destroyed
        if( !isset( $_SESSION[$sessVar] ) ){
            echo '<br>';
            echo $sessName . ' was "unseted"';
        }else{
            echo '<br>';
            echo $sessName . ' was not "unseted"';
        }
    }
}
?>
<hr>
<a href=prueba_session.php?p=1>test 1 (printing session value)</a>
<br>
<a href=prueba_session.php?p=2>test 2 (kill session)</a>
```

El ejecutarlo $_SESSION['foo'] no es guardada...
La verdad es que me esta volviendo loco.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se carga el archivo `http://.../prueba_session.php`, por primera vez, se inicia una sesión automáticamente, aunque no se imprime nada. Esto es porque se cumple esta condición:

```php
if( !isset( $_GET['p'] ) )
```

Al presionar **test 1**, se imprime correctamente una sesión:

```
foo: hello world
PHPSESSID: qmupkob6kb1v6v89khq08jtbg0
```

Al presionar **test 2**, se imprime correctamente la destrucción de la variable.

El problema está cuando se vuelve a presionar **test 1** y se debe al mismo bloque que se mencionó al principio:

```php
if( !isset( $_GET['p'] ) ){
    // instantiate new session var
    $_SESSION[$sessVar] = 'hello world';
}else{
    ....
```

Si observas en el navegador, cuando presionas **test 2**, en la URL se queda `?p=2`; y cuando presionas **test 1** se coloca `?p=1`.
En el bloque de código anterior estás indicando que la variable de sesión se setee **unicamente** cuando no hay variables en la URL, o sea, una vez cierras la sesión ya no se va a volver a setear nunca más y por eso marca el error.